# Set a filter with distinct values

Tags: react-admin

Is there a way to setup something like a `<SelectInput>` filter on a column of the list to get only distinct values of this column ?
Something like the `<ReferenceInput>` but on the same table and with unique values ...

Answer (score 0):

No, but for good reason.  Say you have data with billions of distinct records.  You don't want your frontend determining what is unique.  Instead you want an API that can support that data specifically, and hopefully quickly.
So long story short, you'll need an API for that.

Answer (score 0):

Along the lines of what Shawn K says, perhaps create a View on your backend that represents the state of what is currently 'distinct', acknowledging that it might be stale/non-realtime. Then you could use the contents of that View to represent the choices available to the user.  If generating the distinct set of values is non-performant, then if you're in a DB like Postgres (et al), create a Materialized View, refreshed on a timer.

The binding of the view data to the  becomes the trick at that point, but there are probably clues to doing that here of SO and you could piece these two together.

BTW, I use Views regularly to handle edge certain edge cases like this. Beats caching data in a middle tier for sure.